# Django Parler how to access translated model field from a mixin

Tags: django, python-2.7, mixins, django-parler

I have written this model.

```
class Course(TranslatableModel):
    translations = TranslatedFields(
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200),
        overview = models.TextField(),
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True))
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='courses_created')
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, related_name='courses')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    order = OrderField(blank=True, for_fields=['title'])

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('order',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

AND ALSO THIS mixin class

```
class OwnerCourseEditMixin(OwnerCourseMixin, OwnerEditMixin):
    fields = ['subject', 'title', 'slug', 'overview']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('manage_course_list')
    template_name = 'courses/manage/course/form.html'
```

The "fields = ['subject', 'title', 'slug', 'overview']" line is causing the error

Exception Type: FieldError
Exception Value: Unknown field(s) (overview, slug, title) specified for Course

How do I refer to the translated fields? If I remove 'title', 'slug', 'overview' from the fields list it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED

When translated fields are created django-parler creates a model for each translatable model. So, the model to work with is not the Course model itself, but the generated CourseTranslation model.

I still needed to add the subject field to the Translation model, then all worked.